# Can anyone identify this plant

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors

I randomly bought it and it’s been thriving well, but I don’t know what plant it is.

I live in Karachi, Pakistan. This plant is placed indoor, however its in lounge and is exposed to approx 1.5 to 2hr of afternoon sunlight from right above it. I water this pot after a gap of 1 or 2 days. The bark looks dramatic and is more whitish then grey.

Please help me identify.

[image: Stem]
[image: new leaf emerging]
[image]
[image: leaf]
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for adding us to your network sites! Can you give us some more information please? Where do you live? What are you doing with light, water, etc.? Is it inside or out? (I can't quite tell.) Thanks for the great pictures!! Is all of the bark gray like that? Can you hold a few leaves out of the way and add a view where the plant meets the pot like in the third picture? [Identification](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) questions can be tough, so we ask for as much information as possible! Thanks!

Comment: @Sue Hi, I've just added one more photo you asked for, I live in Karachi, Pakistan. This plant is placed indoor, however its in lounge and is exposed to approx 1.5 to 2hr of afternoon sunlight from right above it. I water this pot after a gap of 1 or 2 days. Yes the bark looks dramatic and is more whitish then grey

Comment: Thanks for the extra information and another great picture! I added the text from the comment into the question so it would all be in one place, and because comments tend to disappear!

Answer (score 4):

Firdous, you have an avocado plant, probably grown from a stone. Carefully scrape away some soil from the base and see if you can see some remnants of the hard shell. Your specimen seems to be some years old however, so the shell might be gone. To verify details, find pictures online of the avocado bark and compare to yours, also note the alternate veining on the sub-veins off the main vein and the slightly wavy edge of the leaf.

Another small detail that argues in favour of an avocado is that the young branches, when trimmed, show that they have a soft pith which dries out and leaves what looks like a hollow cavity. See your picture 1.

Comment: Gees, I was thinking to myself avocado but what a wonderfully branched avocado.  He must get some serious light from above!

Answer (score 1):

I know it is tough to get proper potting soil where you live.  I can see this is garden soil with egg shells on top.  But your dang avocado is happy.  My rule is if it ain't broken don't fix it.  You've heard that right?

If you are using egg shells...I am wondering what you've done for fertilizer.  Your watering seems to be working but I am seeing chemistry deficiencies, not terrible, but have you fertilized with a balanced fertilizer containing the 3 biggies?  N-P-K?  Is there a chance you might be planting this guy out of doors?  What zone is Pakistan? Do you have freezes in Pakistan's winter.  I wish I were more worldly.

The only thing I would do right now is add a bit of balanced fertilizer unless you've already used fertilizer, if so, then we need to look to your watering program.  Others from India and Pakistan have told us they are unable to get proper sterilized potting soil mixtures (these bagged potting soils usually have very little if any actual soil).  You guys don't have the acreage that we have in the States so the only way to grow plants is in pots, indoors or on balconies.  And someone should start selling sterilized potting mix in your part of the world!  Plants in pots really need potting soil or rather potting medium, sterilized, that does NOT come with fertilizer or water holding gimmicks to ensure success. We in the states can find this stuff in our grocery stores.

Careful with the watering.  Your soil looks like it has clay in it, a good thing btw for gardens, but the drainage is horrid if used as a medium for potted plants.  I am sure you have a hole at the bottom of this pot, yes? A little balanced fertilizer and then get back to us with results in 2 weeks?

How long ago did you purchase this plant?  Where was this plant when you first saw it and then purchased it?  Out of doors or in doors or in a green house?  Is this the original pot and soil from the nursery?  Plants acclimated to the out of doors or even a green house will have trouble when abruptly made to live in doors. Same with plants grown under artificial lights and indoors. To take them outside to plant they need an acclimation period. Do you happen to have a covered patio or balcony?  Could you afford a fan and artificial lights?

Don't spray water on the leaves.  Pakistan has humidity in the air or is it dry?  Spraying water or misting does nothing for your plants, does not raise the humidity even temporarily.  A shallow tray of pebbles with water half way up the pebbles is the best micro humidifier.  If you need humidity.

There are some fungal spots showing so I would definitely reduce the watering.

A bit more information, please, so we are more able to personalize this answer.